Unable to connect to elasticsearch with golang and elasticsearch-v8
The method i'm using:
func getESClient() (*elasticsearch.Client, error) {

    cfg := config.LoadEnv()
    cloudId := cfg.ElasticCloudId
    apiKey := cfg.ElasticSearchApiKey

    log.Println("Using CloudID:", cloudId)

    client, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(elasticsearch.Config{
        CloudID: string(cloudId),
        APIKey:  apiKey,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to connect to the Elasticsearch client:", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    log.Println(client.Info())
    log.Println("Client info")
    return client, nil
}

The error i'm getting:
2024/06/14 20:04:16 [401 Unauthorized] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate with provided credentials and anonymous access is not allowed for this request","additional_unsuccessful_credentials":"API key: Illegal base64 character 3a","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate with provided credentials and anonymous access is not allowed for this request","additional_unsuccessful_credentials":"API key: Illegal base64 character 3a","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}}

ELASTICSEARCH_API_KEY=https://id.westus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:443
ELASTICSEARCH_CLOUD_ID=elasticsearch:id==
Using "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8"
I don't have access direct to the elasticsearch node, it gets more complicated. Anyone have a hint over it?

"API key: Illegal base64 character 3a" implies that they key you're specifying for connection isn't actually in base64 format. If you look at the [Elasticsearch API Key documentation][1] you need to provide the encoded value. From your question it looks like you're specifying a URL rather than an API key so try updating that and see if it can connect.
[1]: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-create-api-key.html#:~:text=API%20key%20credentials%20which%20is,encoded%20value%20from%20the%20response).
